# How do I stop a function of a parent movieclip when in a child of that parents?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Help!!

I have a piece of code on a mc that when the mouse is dragged it plays through that movie clip, giving a 360 spin of a product.

Inside this movieclip on different increments of the 360 spin i have child movieclips with various other animations to relate to each angle of the product.

exp..

Scene 1 > spinY_mc > AWComplete_mc

My code for the spin is written within the actions in scene1 and controls spinY_mc but once im in AWComplete_mc i do not want you to be able to drag the mouse and spin?

Im sure this is simple but im a noob at all this and am taking on a mammoth project!

Here is the code used on the movieclip (spinY_mc) I dont want this code to work when inside of its child mc (AWComplete_mc).

```
  // Rotation of Control Body Y

spin_Y.stop();
spin_Y.buttonMode = true;

var spin_Y:MovieClip;
var offsetFrame:int = spin_Y.currentFrame;
var offsetY:Number = 0;
var percent:Number = 0;


spin_Y.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
spin_Y.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // start listening for mouse movement
    spin_Y.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,drag);
    offsetY = stage.mouseY;
}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // STOP listening for mouse movement
    spin_Y.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,drag);
    // save the current frame number;
    offsetFrame = spin_Y.currentFrame;
}

// this function is called continuously while the mouse is being dragged

function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // work out how far the mouse has been dragged, relative to the width of the spin_Y
    // value between -1 and +1
    percent = (mouseY - offsetY) / spin_Y.height;
    // trace(percent);

    // work out which frame to go to. offsetFrame is the frame we started from
    var frame:int = Math.round(percent * spin_Y.totalFrames) + offsetFrame;

    // reset when hitting the END of the spin_Y timeline
    while (frame > spin_Y.totalFrames)
    {
        frame -=  spin_Y.totalFrames;
    }
    // reset when hitting the START of the spin_Y timeline
    while (frame <= 0)
    {
        frame +=  spin_Y.totalFrames;
    }

    // go to the correct frame
    spin_Y.gotoAndStop(frame);
}
```

Comment: Actually it's  not clear what you're trying to achieve.Can you be more specific?

Comment: Within spinY_mc is 35 movie clips 1 - 35 each mc is a different angle of a product. I have written some code that when the mouse is dragged it plays these movie clips and gives the impression of the product spining round so you can see all angles.

Comment: Within two of theses angles say 1_mc and 35_mc i have more animation that you can interact with. But when im inside this section of the movie clip i dont want to be able to drag how can i remove the function of the parent movieclip inside my child movieclip?

Comment: Show your code, or post your .fla and it will be much easier for everyone to understanding what your asking.   We need to see how your interactions are listened for and handled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just want to stop the propagation of an event from the child so it doesn't make it out to the parent.  If you add a listener for the event you want to block (lets say it's mouseDown you want to block).

```
child_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownBlocker);

private function mouseDownBlocker(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

The way events work is they start at the "deepeest" child which the mouse has a hit event with, then they "bubble" up through all the parents.  By stopping the propagation you block the bubbling from occurring, so the parents never get the event.

Comment: I want to stop the functions of the parent when in the child, but i cant refer to the parent from within the child? How do i do that?

Comment: By adding this code i can no longer drag throught the first movie clip? ...confused :/

Comment: I think i may have found my problem, the function i use to drag through and play the initial mc (spinY_mc ) looks for stage.mouseY how can i stop it using this function when in my child movieclip (AWComplete_mc)? I cant post the file on here as my company wont allow it but i could post code, how do i do that?

Comment: @Danielle was on a project for a bit there, let me know if your'e still having an issue.  Basically what I'm suggesting here is that you add the code I have above to the AWComplete_mc.  This will block the mouse event from getting to the spinY_mc when the mouse is within the AWComplete_mc.  If this isn't your intention then I'm misunderstanding.